# Modeling five ordinary differenty equations, and plotting them

Tags: python, numpy, ode, odeint

I am new to python and coding in general, I have made this following code run with one set of parameters and now I have set four different functions that have each their own parameters to run. I would like these to all plot together so that we see a step function. thank you in advance. it gives following error

`raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but " ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (1000,)`

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time
from math import e

def func(z,t):
    xh, xf, y, m, n = z
    #para = 3 if 20*day < (t % year) < 60*day else 10
    v1,v2,v3 = 0.0005,0.0006,0.0007
    B1,B2,B3 = 0.1984,0.1593,0.04959
    d1,d2,d3 = 0.02272,0.02272,0.2
    o1,o2 = 0.25,0.75
    S1=S2=S3=0.005
    S4=S5=0.3
    p = 0.13
    u = 500
    k = 0.000075
    a = 0.4784
    r = 0.0165
    K = 8000
    i = 2
    H = e**(-m*k)
    g = ((xh+xf)**i)/((K**i)+((xh+xf)**i))
    R = o1-(o2*(xf/(xh+xf+.002)))
    P1 =(xh+xf)/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    P2 = 1-((m+n)/(a*(xh+y+xf+.002)))
    P3 = y/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    dxhdt = (u*g*H)-(B1*(m*(xh/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((d1+S1)*xh)-((v1*(m+n))*xh)-(xh*R)
    dxfdt = (xh*R)-(B1*(m*(xf/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((p+d2+S2)*xf)-(v2*(m+n)*xf)
    dydt = (B1*(m*P1))-((d3+S3)*y)-((v3*(m+n))*y)
    dmdt =(r*(m*P2))+(B2*(n*P3))-(B3*(m*P1))-(S4*m)
    dndt = (r*(n*P2))-(B2*(n*P3))+(B3*(m*P1))-(S5*n)
    return [dxhdt,dxfdt,dydt,dmdt,dndt]

def func2(z,t):
    xh, xf, y, m, n = z
    #para = 3 if 20*day < (t % year) < 60*day else 10
    v1,v2,v3 = 0.0005,0.0006,0.0007
    B1,B2,B3 = 0.1460,0.1460,0.03721
    d1,d2,d3 = 0.04,0.04,0.2
    o1,o2 = 0.25,0.75
    S1=S2=S3=0.005
    S4=S5=0.3
    p = 0.13
    u = 1500
    k = 0.00003125
    a = 0.5
    r = 0.0165
    K = 12000
    i = 2
    H = e**(-m*k)
    g = ((xh+xf)**i)/((K**i)+((xh+xf)**i))
    R = o1-(o2*(xf/(xh+xf+.002)))
    P1 =(xh+xf)/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    P2 = 1-((m+n)/(a*(xh+y+xf+.002)))
    P3 = y/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    dxhdt = (u*g*H)-(B1*(m*(xh/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((d1+S1)*xh)-((v1*(m+n))*xh)-(xh*R)
    dxfdt = (xh*R)-(B1*(m*(xf/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((p+d2+S2)*xf)-(v2*(m+n)*xf)
    dydt = (B1*(m*P1))-((d3+S3)*y)-((v3*(m+n))*y)
    dmdt =(r*(m*P2))+(B2*(n*P3))-(B3*(m*P1))-(S4*m)
    dndt = (r*(n*P2))-(B2*(n*P3))+(B3*(m*P1))-(S5*n)
    return [dxhdt,dxfdt,dydt,dmdt,dndt]

def func3(z,t):
    xh, xf, y, m, n = z
    #para = 3 if 20*day < (t % year) < 60*day else 10
    v1,v2,v3 = 0.0005,0.0006,0.0007
    B1,B2,B3 = 0.1900,0.1489,0.04750
    d1,d2,d3 = 0.2,0.2,0.2
    o1,o2 = 0.25,0.75
    S1=S2=S3=0.005
    S4=S5=0.3
    p = 0.13
    u = 500
    k = 0.000075
    a = 0.5
    r = 0.0045
    K = 8000
    i = 2
    H = e**(-m*k)
    g = ((xh+xf)**i)/((K**i)+((xh+xf)**i))
    R = o1-(o2*(xf/(xh+xf+.002)))
    P1 =(xh+xf)/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    P2 = 1-((m+n)/(a*(xh+y+xf+.002)))
    P3 = y/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    dxhdt = (u*g*H)-(B1*(m*(xh/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((d1+S1)*xh)-((v1*(m+n))*xh)-(xh*R)
    dxfdt = (xh*R)-(B1*(m*(xf/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((p+d2+S2)*xf)-(v2*(m+n)*xf)
    dydt = (B1*(m*P1))-((d3+S3)*y)-((v3*(m+n))*y)
    dmdt =(r*(m*P2))+(B2*(n*P3))-(B3*(m*P1))-(S4*m)
    dndt = (r*(n*P2))-(B2*(n*P3))+(B3*(m*P1))-(S5*n)
    return [dxhdt,dxfdt,dydt,dmdt,dndt]

def func4(z,t):
    xh, xf, y, m, n = z
    #para = 3 if 20*day < (t % year) < 60*day else 10
    v1,v2,v3 = 0.0005,0.0006,0.0007
    B1,B2,B3 = 0.03384,0.04226,0.008460
    d1,d2,d3 = 0.005263,0.005263,0.005300
    o1,o2 = 0,0.75
    S1=S2=S3=0.005
    S4=S5=0.3
    p = 0.13
    u = 0
    k = 0
    a = 0.4784
    r = 0.0045
    K = 6000
    i = 2
    H = e**(-m*k)
    g = ((xh+xf)**i)/((K**i)+((xh+xf)**i))
    R = o1-(o2*(xf/(xh+xf+.002)))
    P1 =(xh+xf)/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    P2 = 1-((m+n)/(a*(xh+y+xf+.002)))
    P3 = y/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    dxhdt = (u*g*H)-(B1*(m*(xh/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((d1+S1)*xh)-((v1*(m+n))*xh)-(xh*R)
    dxfdt = (xh*R)-(B1*(m*(xf/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((p+d2+S2)*xf)-(v2*(m+n)*xf)
    dydt = (B1*(m*P1))-((d3+S3)*y)-((v3*(m+n))*y)
    dmdt =(r*(m*P2))+(B2*(n*P3))-(B3*(m*P1))-(S4*m)
    dndt = (r*(n*P2))-(B2*(n*P3))+(B3*(m*P1))-(S5*n)
    return [dxhdt,dxfdt,dydt,dmdt,dndt]    

z0=[13000,11000,0,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,365,1000)
xx=odeint(func,z0,t)
xy=odeint(func2,z0,t)
xz=odeint(func3,z0,t)
xu=odeint(func4,z0,t)
plt.figure(1)
for t in range(0,91):
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,1],'y-',label = '$x_f$')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
for t in range(91,182):
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,1],'y-',label = '$x_f$')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
for t in range(182,273):
    plt.plot(t,xz[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    plt.plot(t,xz[:,1],'y-',label = '$x_f$')
    plt.plot(t,xz[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
    plt.plot(t,xz[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
    plt.plot(t,xz[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
for t in range(274,365):
    plt.plot(t,xu[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    plt.plot(t,xu[:,1],'y-',label = '$x_f$')
    plt.plot(t,xu[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
    plt.plot(t,xu[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
    plt.plot(t,xu[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('POPULATION')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please provide an [mcve]? If that is not possible please show us the differential equations you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace

```py
for t in range(0,91):
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    ...
```

with

```
plt.plot(t[0:91],xx[0:91,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
...
```

You might then perhaps also want to use the vector `xx[91]` as initial value for the integration of `xy` over `t[91:]`. But then you have to account for the index shift in `xy`,...